# Java - Handle indentation in "getTextContent()" of DOM parsed XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, indentation

I've written some java code that parses an XML using DOM for loading data in a program of mine.
Formatting the XML with Eclipse "format" function, I've encountered a problem: the previous working getTextContent() from a document element, now returns a string that contains the whitespaces (or whatelse) added from Eclipse's formatting.
I'm looking for a solution that given:

`<myElement>` some text

of mine

`</myElement>`

when I code-select the element `<myElement>` from the document, I want the getTextContent() to behave like:

`myElement.getTextContent().equals("some text of mine");`

while it actually fails.

If I'm being too non-specific, tell me,
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helper function to pack XML text content.

```
public String getPackedContent(Element element) {
    if (element != null) {
        String text = element.getTextContent();
        if (text != null) {
            return text.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        }
    }
    return "";
}

System.out.print(getPackedContent(myElement)); // "some text of mine"
```

`String#replaceAll()` takes a regex expression to search the string for matches that should be replaced with the substitution string passed as the second argument. `\\s+` means one or more (`+`) whitespaces (`\s`) which includes new lines. The first `\` escapes the actual `\` required in `\s`.

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try! What does the regex expression "\\s+" stands for?

Comment: @iMineLink It means one or more (`+`) whitespaces (`\s`) which includes new lines. The first `\` escapes the actual `\` required in `\s`.

Comment: I've tried your snippet in my code and it worked flawlessly. Thank you very much!