# Read XML node value containing white spaces

Tags: java, xml

I am working on a java program that reads from a xml file. The input string to be read is:

```
<xmlnode>ABC

       XYZ</xmlnode>
```

I am using the getTextContent() method of Element class to read the value of this node. I want to print the extra white spaces that are before the 'XYZ' string in the second line. However, those spaces are ignored. I also tried the getNodeValue() method but the output still remains the same.

Comment: Does this help `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289235/java-handle-indentation-in-gettextcontent-of-dom-parsed-xml`

Comment: How are you parsing it? Have you set your parser to preserve whitespace?

Comment: @Abhi's link as an [actual link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289235/java-handle-indentation-in-gettextc‌​ontent-of-dom-parsed-xml).

Comment: The problem is that this is a legacy code that I cannot change as a whole. This is read node by node. The code constructs a different string based on the node attributes and the value.

Comment: @Abhi : Well that link actually replaces the spaces. I need to preserve the white space.

Comment: element.getTextContent().replaceAll("\\s"," ") preserves whitespaces as is.

Comment: you need to remove + from \\s+

Comment: @user3487063, that doesn't work either. The line return is also removed by that. I need to preserve carriage returns as well as white spaces, which can be more than 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like below might work:

```
String content= element.getTextContent();
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
content = content.replaceAll("\\s"," ");
String [] arr= content.split("\r"); //split on newline or cr
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   sb.append(arr[i])
     .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
content = sb.toString();
```

Comment: The issue to start with is the with getTextContent() as it does not read the characters before 'XYZ'. If I use your code, I may get only 1 space. I need to retain the spaces also.